# how to create a user rule that can only manage support tickets?

Tags: php, user-roles

I want to add a user rule so users with that rule can only receive and respond to "support tickets", nothing more. what code should i put in my site?

Comment: How have you implemented these support tickets - as custom post types? How do users receive and respond to them, through the front-end of the site or through the admin site? When you say 'only', what other features are there in your site you want to deny them?

Comment: it's not for the user. I want it for my staff. Other features are articles, pages, yoasSeo, shipping plugin, woocomerce,  etc. As for implementing support tickets as custom post type, i don't know if they're implemented so or not. but the plugin is installed.

Comment: users sign up on the site, and they send them through their own profile which is the woocomerce My-Account-Page. There's a menu in there, labeled as "support" which they can send tickets from there.